# How to use SharedPreferences to save a scrolling checklist from the CustomAdapter

Tags: android, custom-adapter, android-sharedpreferences

I'm writing a program and for this step in the program, I need a scrolling checklist that will save what the user checked so that when the Activity is closed and re-opened the checklist will maintain what the user checked.

The problem I'm having is that I'm not able to save the position of the check item along with its boolean value.

*This is my CustomAdapter:*

```
SharedPreferences mSettings = getContext().getSharedPreferences("Settings", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();

boolean dog;
private final List<MenuRow> list;
private final Activity context;
boolean checkAll_flag = false;
boolean checkItem_flag = false;

public CustomRowAdapter(Activity context, List<MenuRow> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.menurow_layout, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent /*CompoundButton buttonView*/) {



    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.menurow_layout, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {



            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {



                if(mSettings==null) {
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  
                    list.get(getPosition).setSelected(buttonView.isChecked()); 
                    if(isChecked) {

                        editor.putInt("Position", (Integer) buttonView.getTag());
                        editor.putBoolean("CheckPosition", isChecked);
                        editor.apply();
                    }else{

                        editor.putInt("Position", (Integer) buttonView.getTag());
                        editor.putBoolean("CheckPosition", isChecked=false);
                        editor.apply();
                    }
                }

                else {
                    SharedPreferences mSettings = getContext().getSharedPreferences("Settings", 0);

                    int getPosition = mSettings.getInt("Position", (Integer) buttonView.getTag());

                    mSettings.getBoolean("CheckPosition", isChecked );

                    list.get(getPosition).setSelected(isChecked);

                }

            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.textView1, viewHolder.text);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.check, viewHolder.checkbox);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(position); // This line is important.

    viewHolder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    viewHolder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try to save the `position` argument directly?

Comment: I haven't, but what I need is some way to save the position of the checkbox with its boolean so that when I leave the activity the checklist saves.

Comment: Try try saving the `position` directly instead of the tag.